# how to display multiple query result in a same page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Please have a look at the below code snippet.I am using several post query in a same page but unable to show output in every output

```
<div class="col-md-4 single-content">
<?php       
    $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=news&category_name=current news&posts_per_page=1' );

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

             <h4 class="title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
             <p class="add-info"><?php the_date(); ?></p>

             <?php the_content(); 
        endwhile;
    endif; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>    
</div> <!-- End of single-content -->

<div class="col-md-4 single-content">
    <div class="headbar"><h3>Organization News</h3></div>
        <?php       
            $my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=news&category_name=organization news&posts_per_page=1' );

            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();?>

                    <h4 class="title"><?php the_title();?></h4>
                    <p class="add-info"><?php the_date(); ?></p>

                     <?php the_content();
                endwhile;
            endif; 
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>    
</div> <!-- End of single-content -->
```

It's not showing the result of php_date function in the second loop. Can some please help me to how this work out.

Comment: Your `category_name`s have spaces in them. I don't think that wordpress category slugs can contain spaces.

Comment: Fixed those things but still not working @alpipego

Answer (score 0):

`wp_reset_query()` is only necessary after `query_posts()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query. You should use `wp_reset_postdata()` instead.

Sidenote: As mentioned in my comment, your category slugs can't contain spaces, so your queries will not work as expected (if at all).